# Multi-table unconditional fetching rows from sub-query confusion

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
INSERT ALL
 INTO sal_history (empid,hiredate,sal)
 VALUES (empid,hiredate,sal)
 INTO mgr_history (empid,mgr,sal)
 VALUES (empid,mgr,sal)
SELECT employee_id AS "EMPID",
       hire_date   AS "HIREDATE",
       salary      AS "SAL",
       manager_id  AS "MGR"
FROM   employees
WHERE  employee_id > 200;
```

How does the insert into clause know in this whole statement which columns to select for the insertion in the multi tables `sal_history` and `mgr_history`? As I can see there are 3 columns in `sal_history` and 3 in `mgr_history`, but in the sub-query there are 4.

I know how this statement works, for each row in the subquery the "insert_into_clause" executes only once but this not the point, it is just this small little thing I don't understand about the columns.

Comment: Because the VALUES clauses specify which of the 4 columns to use.

Comment: I knew that, that is all?, no other "tricks"?

Comment: What more tricks would it need?  It is very explicit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the `INTO` clauses specifies which columns to populate for that table, and the matching `VALUES` clause specifies which of the columns *from the subquery* to use. In this case the subquery is using the same names, which might be a little confusing; perhaps you'd find it clearer with different aliases:

```
INSERT ALL
 INTO sal_history (empid,hiredate,sal)
 VALUES (sub_empid,sub_hiredate,sub_sal)
 INTO mgr_history (empid,mgr,sal)
 VALUES (sub_empid,sub_mgr,sub_sal)
SELECT employee_id AS "SUB_EMPID",
       hire_date   AS "SUB_HIREDATE",
       salary      AS "SUB_SAL",
       manager_id  AS "SUB_MGR"
FROM   employees
WHERE  employee_id > 200;
```

All four of the subquery columns (aliases) are used in the `VALUES` clauses; three in each, with both `SUB_EMPID` and `SUB_SAL` (with my hopefully-clarifying prefix) appearing in both.